# PyQt5 Login to Register Dialog Auto Close

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a login and register dialog, and of course a main window. So, I want the users to be able to switch between login and register dialog, and if the user enters correct credentials, the user can go to the main window. If the user registered a new credential, then the user will be redirected to the login window. That said, the first interface that the user see is the login dialog. Here are some codes for login-register dialog:

```
class Login(QDialog):
    # Push Button -> Login
    # Push Button 2 -> To Register
    # Push Button 3 -> Exit
    def __init__(self):
        super(Login, self).__init__()
        # Load Login UI
        loadUi("Login.ui", self)
        # Set Translucent Background for the Windows
        self.setWindowFlags(PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        # Set Push Button 1 to call the function upon clicked
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.check_login)
        # Set Push Button 2 to call the function upon clicked
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.redirect_to_register)
        # Set Push Button 3 to call the function upon clicked
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.close_window)
        # Show the Window
        self.show()

    # Procedure to redirect to register windows
    def redirect_to_register(self):
        self.close()  # Close the login windows
        # Show the register windows
        self.register = Register()
        self.register.show()
...

class Register(QDialog):
    # Push Button -> Register
    # Push Button 2 -> To Login
    # Push Button 3 -> Exit
    def __init__(self):
        # Load Register UI
        super(Register, self).__init__()
        loadUi("Register.ui", self)
        # Set Translucent Background for the Windows
        self.setWindowFlags(PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        # Set Push Button 2 to call the function upon clicked
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.insert_to_database)
        # Set Push Button 2 to call the function upon clicked
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.redirect_to_login)
        # Set Push Button 3 to call the function upon clicked
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.close_window)
        # Show the Window
        self.show()

    # Procedure to redirect to login windows
    def redirect_to_login(self):
        # Close the login windows
        self.close()
        # Show the register windows
        self.login = Login()
        self.login.show()

    def close_window(self):
        self.close()
```

I load the .ui file of both dialog. But, for the main window, the .py file is converted from the .ui file. That said, in the main of the login file, I call the main window with this code:

```
import GoodLife
# Call main
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Init App
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QtGui.QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont("../img/dripicons-v2.ttf")
    # Build the window
    window = Login()
    if(window.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted):
        GoodLife = QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(GoodLife)
        GoodLife.setWindowTitle("Good Life - Your Dear Bestfriend :)")
        GoodLife.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('../img/goodlife.jpg'))
        GoodLife.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

With that code, I am able to go into the main window after logging in. But, whenever I tried to switch to register dialog, the register dialog keeps auto-closing. I believe that the line `sys.exit(app.exec_())` is the cause of it, because when I unindent the line once, I can go to the register, but not the main window. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when a dialog is closed, it exits its event loop (the one launched with `exec`) with a `Rejected` result.

In your case, since the rejection doesn't match `window.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted`, the result is that that whole block is not evaluated, and the application simply exits.

A simple solution would be to *hide* the login until the registration is completed (or rejected) and show it again afterwards.

Since the login dialog should be shown anyway, there's no need for custom signals or if statements, as it's enough to call the registration dialog's exec_ in the `redirect_to_register` function, so that you can show again the login no matter the result of the registration.

Unfortunately, there's a problem with that: in Qt, hiding a dialog results in a behavior similar to closing it (so, rejecting).
The solution is to avoid the base implementation of QDialog (which overrides both `hide()` and `setVisible()`), and use that of QWidget instead:

```
   def redirect_to_register(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.setVisible(self, False)
        self.register = Register()
        self.register.exec_()
        self.show()
```

This also means that in the register dialog you should not try to recreate the login window:

```
class Register(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.accept)
```

Some unasked suggestions:

- in the last code you're importing "GoodLife", then not only you're not using it, but you're also overwriting it as a *variable*; you probably did some copy/paste/edit error, but the point is that names that begin with uppercase letters should only be used for classes and constants, not for variables;
- there's no need to implement a `close_window` function if it just calls `self.close()`: just connect signals to `self.close`;
- be more verbose with object names, including widgets you create in Designer: having lots of `pushButton_x` is never a good idea, as you cannot easily distinguish their role;
- commenting should be limited to sections in which it's not immediate what the code does; comments like "Set Push Button 2 to call the function upon clicked" or "Show the window" are completely useless and distracting as they don't add any information;
- window title and icons can be set in Designer;
- be careful with relative paths, especially for parent (`../`) folders; consider using Qt resource systems (which also allows you to set icons and images directly in Designer);

Comment: @Richard I don't see why the taskbar would be full, hiding and showing a dialog doesn't add items to the taskbar every time. In any case, before asking, read, understand and *try* the code. The login dialog is shown again in *any* case when the register dialog is closed, as this is exactly what you asked. See the update.

Comment: yeah my bad there was a little error when I tried it and it fills my taskbar. That aside, I am able to switch between the dialogs. I can also go to the main window, but only in my first login dialog. When I switched back to login from register, the main window auto-closes. What happens here?

Comment: Ok, fixed. Sorry but since you were using ui files I couldn't test your code with my modifications, so I answered only by reasoning and forgot that `hide()` also triggers the `done()` of QDialog (which results like closing it). Calling the *QWidget* base implementation of `setVisible` (*not* `hide()`!) solves the problem. See the update.

Comment: hey really appreciate the magic! I am now able to switch and go to the main but sadly a new issue appears. I switch from login to register. I tried registering someone, it succeeded and then I am redirected to the login dialog, and until this point, it is according to what I want. But, when I try to login in that dialog, the main window just doesn't appear. I will edit the post with my current code just in case something is wrong with my understanding. Edited..

Comment: @Richard please don't edit the question with code retrieved from an answer, it makes it very confusing to anybody trying to understand what is your actual problem. I'm restoring back your previous text. Then, if in your `check_login` you're calling `close()` you should remember that, as said, closing a dialog results in *rejecting* it, and since you're going to show the main window only when the dialog is *accepted*, you must call `self.accept()` or `self.done(1)`.

Comment: Ah sorry about that and thank you for restoring it. And yes, I am using `self.accept()` in the `check_login` if the input is valid, and it still does not work.

Comment: @Richard I believe that the problem might be related to the first suggestion I made at the end of my answer: I don't see any `from ... import Ui_MainWindow`, and there's the problem of that `import GoodLife` that you're overwriting. Unfortunately, without any other context, it's a bit difficult to help you, so I suggest you to better check your code (and try to run it in a terminal/prompt to see if there's some debug), and eventually create a *new* question about that, since the problem doesn't seem related to this question.

Comment: thank you for the guides so far, really appreciate it! I made a new post with some additional context here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67142068/switch-between-login-register-dialogs-and-to-main-windows-pyqt5. Kindly check it if you do not mind. :D

Comment: Ah I'm really sorry I forgot to delete the `redirect_to_login` after the registration is done, that is why the `Login` dialog keeps getting remade. That said, it works now! Thank you so much for the help! Sorry to keep you for so long because of my own mistake.